# How to calculate probability that a random variable is greater than an expression having a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the probability of the following:
$P\left(Z_j>\frac{\epsilon}{a*R}\left(\sum^{M}_{m=j+1} ~ b*R*X_m+1\right)\right)$

where $Z$ and $X$ are independent and identically distributed random variables.

$a$, $b$, $\epsilon$, and $R$ are constants

Comment: what have you tried so far? what theorems/other results are you familiar with?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let's try writing things clear
$$
X = \{X_1, X_2,...,X_m\}
$$

$$
y^* = max\{y_1,...,y_m\}
$$

$$
P(X<y^*) = P(X_1,...,X_m < y^*) = 1 - P(X \geq y^*) = 1- P(X_1,...,X_m \geq y^*)
$$
Now, apply your hypothesis about the $X_m$... what can you say about the last term?